# How to style to display the input search box inside a div

Tags: css

I would like to display the `search nominations...` input text inside the above div with class name `nominationsearch_Home` I have tried the following css, but not looking good. Any advise on this one please ?

```
.nominationsearch_Home {
  width: 230px !important;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(156,160,171,.25);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.nominationsearch_Icon img{
  height:30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  display :flex;
}

input {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px !important;
}

     



      <label>
        <div className="nominationsearch_Home">
            <div className="nominationsearch_Icon">
                <img alt="" src="/images/search.png"></img>
            </div>
           <input type="text" className="nomination_Home_Input" placeholder="search nominations..."/>
        </div>
    </label>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flex

```
.nominationsearch_Home {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, the display property helped me to fix the issue. Upvoted and accepted !